# group_by on several (many) variables

Tags: dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

This is simple question, I guess. when using `group_by()` from dplyr on several variables, can I use colon instead of comma to group variables?

Imagine I have V1 to V10 variables, and I want to group according to the first five. Do I need to:

```
group_by(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5)
```

Or can I:

```
group_by(V1:V5)
```

It seems I cannot, but is there any other alternative?

Thanks a lot.

Best,

David

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67958155/group-byacrossall-ofvars-years-grouping-by-variables-with-a-fixed-year)

Comment: Thanks a lot Julian. `across()` did the trick for me. Best, David.